# bazaar ignore file

Tags: bazaar

what is the equivalent of the **.hgignore** mercurial file in **bazaar**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

.bzrignore (at the top of the repository tree), or ~/.bazaar/ignore (for global ignores). Much more information is easily found on the Bazaar site/tutorial - e.g. http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/bzr-0.9/tutorial.html.

Answer (score 6):

If you are on Windows the global ignore file is in `%appdata%\Bazzar\2.0\ignore`

Comment: Also you can add individual ignores via command line. "bzr ignore *.txt" would ignore all with the .txt extention. Not exactly what you were looking for, but it works as well.

Underneath it just adds things to the ignore file in that repo.

Comment: I think that using **%appdata%\*Bazaar*\2.0\ignore** is better because actually i am using Vista